# How do I connect Hazelcast with Hbase?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, in-memory-database, hazelcast

I have both Hazelcast and HBase . I have million entries in my HBase . How do I establish a connection with HBase from Hazelcast so that I access these entries from Hazelcast. If that is not possible how can I enter these records in Hazelcast?
Thanks in Advance.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the blog explains how HBase and Hazelcast can be integrated: http://blog.codepoly.com/distribute-with-hazelcast-persist-into-hbase

The point is you store some of the data in Hazelcast (the most recent or frequently used ones), namely use Hazelcast as cache. See eviction options:
http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.5/manual/single_html/#MapEviction

After integrating HBase, each get() will load record from HBase into Hazelcast.